# Using CKRecord query return as original data

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation, ckrecord

After uploading locations to cloud kit, I want to be able to download them into an array as CLLocations.  As of right now I get the CKRecords, but can not use them as CLLocations anymore.

```
func loadLocation()
     {
        let locations = [CKRecord]()
        let publicData1 = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        let query1 = CKQuery(recordType: "location", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray:nil))
        publicData1.performQuery(query1, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results: [CKRecord]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let locations = results
            {
                self.locations = locations
                print(locations)
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: You nave to access your location field of each record.

Comment: how would i do that @rmaddy

Comment: Use `objectForKey:` function of `CKRecord`.

Comment: it keeps telling me that "value of [CKRecord] has no member 'objectForKey' " @rmaddy

Comment: You have to use it on each individual CKRecord, not the array.

Comment: would you mind giving me an example of how to implement it on my code above? @rmaddy